# Writing answer for interval of monotocity

Tags: calculus

Suppose we have to find the interval in which the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, f(x)=x^3-3x+2$ is monotonically decreasing.

Now should the answer be $[-1,-1]$ or $(-1,1)$?

Comment: The answer is $(-1,1)$.